# How to check capacity of priority queue?

Tags: java, collections

In Vector there is `capacity()` method to check the current capacity but in PriorityQueue how to check the same,there is no ready-made method available in 
Queue/PriorityQueue like in Vector. If i trying to implement Vector method it shows size instead of capacity of Queue.

```
 import java.util.*;

    class QueueAdd
    {

    public static void main(String []args)
    {

    PriorityQueue pq=new PriorityQueue(20);

    pq.add('3');
    pq.add('@');
    pq.add('2');
    pq.add('3');
   System.out.println("Added elements in PriorityQueue-"+pq);

    Vector v= new Vector(pq);

    System.out.println(v);

    System.out.println(v.capacity()); // 4
    System.out.println(v.size());   //4
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the `Vector` class is so extremely old, you should never use it. It even says so in its own documentation. Use the modern alternatives. By definition of a `PriorityQueue` they don't need to offer any capacity or so. So you don't get access. It may be possible that a specific implementation internally has some capacity, you will then need to check if maybe the specific class offers access. But a the `PriorirityQueue` interface doesn't offer any capacity.

Comment: @Zabuza "You should never use it. It even says so in its own documentation"  That is false. The documentation does not say that. (although I agree not to use it)

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

> A priority queue is unbounded, but has an internal capacity governing the size of an array used to store the elements on the queue. It is always at least as large as the queue size. As elements are added to a priority queue, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified.

This means there is no specific capacity, it only has a size()

Comment: public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity)
Creates a PriorityQueue with the specified initial capacity that orders its elements according to their natural ordering.   then what is this mean that it has to be have initial capacity

Comment: @Pratik That argument is used to set the initial internal capacity, which will still grow automatically. The same way [ArrayList takes an initial capacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-). It's an optimisation to avoid reallocating an internal array when you know/expect the size to be at least a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
System.out.println("Capacity :"+ findCapacity(pq));


static int findCapacity(PriorityQueue<Character> pq) throws Exception {

    Field field = PriorityQueue.class.getDeclaredField ("queue");

    field.setAccessible(true);

    return ((Object[]) field.get(pq)).length;

}

Result:
Capacity :20
```

Comment: While this approach works, please never deploy any of this if you don't must to. Using reflection to hack your way through is not good and it will break if someone ever changes the classes internals. If the class doesn't offer access, it's not meant to be accessed.